# regex to match string with a minimum number of words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need a regex to match a string only if it contains at least X words (where a word is defined as any continuous non-whitespace sequence).

I am using `re.findall()`.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: i seem to be getting catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: Sorry but without any attempt this looks like "please do my homework"

Comment: well last time i got homework there was still no internet, but thanks for the compliment.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Very mature of you, downvoting all my questions.

Comment: I believe that the question is relevant and well-defined and that together with the accepted answer will be helpful to others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, you could use the character class `\S+` to designate a word.

`\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]` which is itself equivalent to `[^ \v\t\f\n\r]` (in order I typed them: white space, vertical tab, horizontal tab, form feed, newline, carriage return).

`[^ ... ]` indicates a negated class, where all characters will be matched, except those inside the class.

Now, for what you're trying to do, I would rather use `re.match` like so:

```
re.match(r'\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){X-1,}', text_to_validate)
```

`(?:\s+\S+)` matches space(s) followed by a word.

`{X-1,}` means that the group `(?:\s+\S+)` should appear at least `X-1` times to match. If X=4, then it becomes `{3,}`.

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/bNjG2g)

---

Alternate, split on spaces and count the number of elements:

```
re.split(r"\s+", text_to_validate)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/g52nbC)

Comment: doesn't "0 or more times" imply you would match a string of X consecutive non-whitespace characters? how would you do it with re.findall?

Comment: @eyaler Sorry, I edited the regex. I had overlooked something very important. To your first question, no, the presence of `\S+` forces the regex to match at least a word. To your second question, you could use the same regex. It's just that your way of checking whether the `text_to_validate` passes or not. `re.match` returns an object, `re.findall` returns a list.

Comment: @eyaler Not sure if there's any issue with the solution I proposed, but I added a demo to the answer.

Comment: the findall should match the whole string in a single match, for this you need to add .* after your match string. i ended up using:
re.findall(r'.*?\S(?:\s+\S+){' + str(X-1) + '}.*?', text)

Comment: @eyaler You don't need to put those `.*?`. You just forgot the `,` in the quantifier which makes it work without `.*?`: `re.findall(r'\s*\S(?:\s+\S+){' + str(X-1) + ',}', text)`. The `.*?` can be quite slow, but if performance doesn't bother you, that's okay.

Comment: because your match cannot end with a whitespace

Comment: Sentences are not supposed to end with whitespaces, and that extra white space won't change the functionality of the regex in this context, but that's up to you how you implement it. I just suggesting that solution.

Answer (score -2):

```
import re

subject = """I need a regex to match a string only if it contains at least X words.
Where a word is defined as any continuous non-whitespace sequence.
I am using Python 3 and re.findall()"""

result = re.findall(r"([\S]+)", subject)

if len(result) > 5:
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

http://labs.codecademy.com/

Comment: the findall should match the whole string in a single match